# Team city artifact dependency get last build artifact not latest

Tags: dependencies, teamcity, artifact

We are using Teamcity for our Build and Deploy of our web application. We are using MSBuild to build the application and MSDeploy to deploy. We want to use two different build config's one to build and the other to deploy.

Now the question we have is in teamcity when we use Artifact Dependency how to deploy a build package that was last build in the build config and not the last latest changeset build. In case of an older changeset build for deployment after a later changeset teamcity does not seem to take the older one on artifcat dependency.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Sarath

Answer (score 1):

The default value of Artefact Dependency is `Build from same chain`

You can set to `Use last successful build` for the Artefact Dependency of the `Build` configuration.

Comment: In Teamcity 9.5 there aren't any last successful build option. Last successful build specified in the documentation is for the last latest changeset successful build. If I perform a build on one or two changesets older after this, teamcity always ignores it.

Answer (score 1):

UI options do not provide a way to download the last build if it was a "history" one. You can use [REST API](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/REST+API#RESTAPI-BuildArtifacts) to download the files within the build script as that allows for flexible builds selection. e.g. request .../app/rest/builds/buildType(id:)/artifacts/content/ should get you the file from the last build even if it is a history one.

However, when you want to deploy a build, relying on the sequence of builds seems to be too fragile an approach. This way you can accidentally deploy the wrong build if it triggered and finished while the deploying build was in the queue.

To ensure a specific build will be deployed, run Deployment build by invoking Actions / Promote while standing on the build to be deployed: this way the actual artifact dependency condition will be forced to the specific build. Any you can deploy any build, including not the latest one.

Also consider using the TeamCity [recommended approach](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/How%20To...#HowTo...-SetupDeploymentforMyApplicationinTeamCity) and configuring Snapshot dependency between the builds to get a visualization on the build's Dependencies tab and Build Chains project/build configuration tabs.

Comment: Thanks Yaegor, apologies not getting back sooner. As a temporary setup we are using a common checkout for the staging & live environment. Your solution seems promising, I will not be able to try it out now. When I do have time, I will try your approach. Thanks